# android add a new place to Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, checkin

i've build an android application which inside you can check in to a Facebook place.
if the place exist in Facebook there is no problem, but i want to give the users an option to add a new place if it doesn't exist (like the option they have within Facebook or Facebook App).
i couldn't find any documentation about it...

can someone please advise on this subject ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i want to give the users an option to add a new place if it doesn't exist

“Places” users can check in to have to be actual *pages* on Facebook with having the appropriate location data set. So what you want is basically to *create* a new Facebook page on the fly for your user to check in to.

This does not make much sense IMHO, because it would create just another “ghost” page with no actual useful info on it, not much action going on there at any foreseeable point in the future … so my advice would be: Don’t do it.

Instead, offer you users to check into any *available* places in their surrounding area – you can use the Graph API to search for those by lat/lon coordinates and a distance, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#searching

Comment: yes i've been using this graph API method to get locations, i just thought maybe there is a simple way of adding a new place like you can do when you're inside facebook